# I need to get the sum of the degrees of actor nodes in the graph with the actor nodes.this graph is bipartite graph which has actor and movie nodes

Tags: python, networkx

My code snippet for graph

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
graded_graph= nx.Graph()
graded_graph.add_nodes_from(['a1','a5','a10','a11'], bipartite=0) 
graded_graph.add_nodes_from(['m1','m2','m4','m6','m5','m8'], bipartite=1)
graded_graph.add_edges_from([('a1','m1'),('a1','m2'),('a1','m4'),('a11','m6'),('a5','m5'), 
('a10','m8')])
l={'a1','a5','a10','a11'};r={'m1','m2','m4','m6','m5','m8'}
pos = {}
pos.update((node, (1, index)) for index, node in enumerate(l))
pos.update((node, (2, index)) for index, node in enumerate(r))
nx.draw_networkx(graded_graph, pos=pos, 
with_labels=True,node_color='lightblue',alpha=0.8,style='dotted',node_size=500)
```

now i want to get the sum of the degrees of the actors nodes and movie nodes separately. if i use graded_graph.degrees(). the output that i get is list of the degrees for both actor and movie nodes. how can i separate them ?

Also how can i get the unique nodes for both movie and actor nodes?

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
graded_graph= nx.Graph()
graded_graph.add_nodes_from(['actor_1','actor_5','actor_10','actor_11'], bipartite=0) 
graded_graph.add_nodes_from(['mov_1','mov_2','mov_4','mov_6','mov_5','mov_8'], bipartite=1)
graded_graph.add_edges_from([('actor_1','mov_1'),('actor_1','mov_2'),('actor_1','mov_4'),
                             ('actor_11','mov_6'),('actor_5','mov_5'), ('actor_10','mov_8')])


gd=graded_graph.to_directed()
dfDegree=pd.DataFrame([{'name':v[0][0],'degree':v[0][1],'type':v[0][0].split('_')[0]} 
                       for v in list(zip(gd.degree)) ])
dfDegreeActor=dfDegree.query('type=="actor"')
dfDegreeMov=dfDegree.query('type=="mov"')
print(dfDegreeActor)
print(dfDegreeMov)
```